# Calculate a third column based on two other columns values for iteration on a fourth column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, iteration

[Results]

[image: 1]

[Input data]

[image: 2]

I have a dataframe in Python:
I want to calculate the subtract of "Start" and "End" columns for each "Product order" in the following way:
for each product number I have "Type"s A to D: I need to subtract the end time of D from start time of A for each product order. Any idea how to do it? Thanks.

Input data:

```
process order   Type   Start   End
111               A     10      20
111               B     22      25
111               C     28       30
111               D     33       35 
222               A     37       40
222               B     42       45
222
222
333
333
333
333
```

like for process order 111: we have D (End: 35) - A (Strat: 10) = 25
Output should be like:

```
process order   Time_difference
111             25
222              ?
333              ?
```

Comment: Please paste your data as tables/code and not as screenshots. Also include any code that you've tried.

Comment: please provide the data as text

Comment: How do you select which value of the start column should be subtracted? I understand they are the yellow ones, but when you load the dataframe from the excel file, the colors won't be there.

Answer (score 0):

Group by your order and then simply take the `end` value from the last row and subtract from it the `start` value from the second row:

```py
df.groupby('order_number').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-1, 'end'] - x.iloc[1, 'start'])
```

If you need to, you can join these results back into the original `df`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all products have Types A to F, try:

```
#sort values so that B is the 2nd and F is the last row for each order number
df = df.sort_values(["order number", "type"])

#groupby order number and keep the 2nd (iat[1]) row for "start" and the last row for "end"
output = df.groupby("order number").agg({"start": lambda x: x.iat[1], "end": "last"})

#compute the difference
diff = output["end"] - output["start"]

>>> diff
order number
103895166    2072
103900419    2228
103902156    9348
dtype: int64
```

###### Input df:

```
    order number type  start    end
0      103895166    A      0   1999
1      103895166    B    361   2067
2      103895166    C    365   2117
3      103895166    D    368   2118
4      103895166    E    497   2423
5      103895166    F    498   2433
6      103900419    A      0   3627
7      103900419    B   2128   3791
8      103900419    C   2132   3841
9      103900419    D   2135   3842
10     103900419    E   2264   4346
11     103900419    F   2454   4356
12     103902156    A      0  12432
13     103902156    B   3852  12938
14     103902156    C   3856  12987
15     103902156    D   3860  13000
16     103902156    E   3864  13100
17     103902156    F   3868  13200
```